# Ruby Regular Expression to match words, including accents and other UTF8 characters

Tags: ruby, regex

We're trying to find a regular expression that allows us to split sentences into words.
Of course, the immediate answer is to use `\w`, except that it doesn't split on `_`which we need. 
Then, we tried `[a-zA-Z0-9]` (we'd like to allow for numbers inside words), the problem is that it splits on accents, which are fairly common in many langues...

So, ideally, what regexp should I use to split the following sentence in the following words :

> "Je ne déguste pas d'asperges, car je n'aime pas ça"

info

> ["Je","ne","déguste","pas","d",
>   "asperges", "car","je",
>   "n","aime","pas", "ça"]

Comment: Have a look at this ruby forum thread:  http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/415626

Comment: How do you want to handle hyphenated words like "middle-aged", "twenty-one", "20th-century"?

Comment: Ideally, the hyphen should be kept. So, "middle-aged" is a valid word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
STR = "Je ne déguste pas d'asperges, car je n'aime pas ça"
words = STR.split /[\s,']+/
for w in words
    print w, "\n"
end
```

The output is:

```
Je
ne
déguste
pas
d
asperges
car
je
n
aime
pas
ça
```